# Removing JDK/NetBeans from Debian

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, debian

I am new to Linux and new to Java.

Previously i had jdk1.8.0_171 installed, along with netbeans 8.2.
During one of the Kali updates, JDK 8 was completely replaced by JDK 10.
As a result of that, netbeans stopped functioning.

I attempted to install JDK 8, and it seemed to work.

```
java -version
```

was showing both 8 and 10 after using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

to select different versions. 
That however had no effect on netbean, it was completely unusable.

Then i made a decision to completely remove everything that had to do with Java, and install a fresh copy of JDK 8.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

and

```
sudo apt-get purge icedtea*
```

was used.

```
java -version and sudo dpkg --list|grep -i jdk
```

was used to make sure nothing was left.
Additionally running

```
apt-get update
```

removed some unused leftovers.

Next i downloaded and executed jdk 8_171 tar.gz file. It ran, but gave some error in the end.

Next i tried to remove Netbeans, but received a message saying that i would need JDK to be installed to do anything about Netbeans.

```
java -version
```

showed nothing. Purging of both openjdk and icedtea did nothing, both say that files are not present.
Then i have tried to install JDK + Netbean combo, and that resulted in error message saying that JDK is already installed.

So now i am in the situation where i cant remove Netbean, Netbean is not working because JDK is not present. JDK cant be installed because apparently i already have JDK. Where JDK was installed i cant figure out, searching manually and with using

```
whereis name
```

is not yielding any meaningful results.

Detailed explanation on what is going on and what should i do about it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [1] What do you mean by _"netbeans stopped functioning"_. Could you start NetBeans and access its menus? [2] What do you mean by _"completely unusable"_? Could you start NetBeans and access its menus? [3] Can you start NetBeans now? If so, it sounds like you just need to set the JDK: **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...**